Replacing 12V battery with a mains switching power supply
I have a cherry picker and the hydraulic motor is 12V running on several expensive 12V batteries. The batteries have failed and as I only use it at home always near mains I want to use a 12 power supply. I checked the motor rating 12V 120amp and bought a 12V 2000W  166amp switching power supply thinking I can just use that instead of batteries. Fitted it and all that happens is the relays click but the motor doesn't run. All works on a 12V battery fine. Am I doing something wrong or is it a faulty power supply? (Chinese aliexpress an I dont trust them)

May need more than 166A to start.

Probably cheaper to change the motor for a mains powered one

can you put a spare battery in parallel with the PSU? Think of it as a giant capacitor.

All of the circuitry is 12v. Not sure how I could fit and operate a mains powered one and be controlled by the 12v system.

Will a 12v battery in parallel harm the power supply?

Are you certain the motor operates at 12 volts? I have never encountered a 12-volt motor with over two plus horsepower. Such a motor would require an excessive amount of copper and current, and it would also be hazardous. I believe the batteries are connected in series to produce 24, 36, or 48 volts using a golf cart motor and controller. Using 12 volts is nucking futs.

The input is 12v as on the manufacturer plate...12v 120amp. There must be a transformer inside  as the motor itself is 24v 3kw 200amp.

DC motors have high efficiency or low losses due to ratio of DCR to the impedance at rated load usually around 10%.
In order to regulate the expected 10x surge current you need an e-motor controller or EMC.
They use switching full FET bridges to limit acceleration with a ramped average voltage.  Alternatively if your PSU has an external linear voltage control input then that might do the same with a slew rate limit.
Another alternative might be to try a 1000+ CCA truck battery in parallel with welding cables and your power supply with some sort of reverse protection when AC is off.
Why do only the relays click?
The PSU will shut down when the voltage drops below spec due to over current limit detected.
If you had LiFeO4 batteries, check the ESR rating. Lead Acid CCA ratings are done at 7.5 V meaning a 5 V drop from full charge at 12.5. Any DC regulated supply won’t allow that but a battery charger will with CC and CV control.
That means even with a 1000A CCA battery in parallel with a 120A PSU you won’t get 1000A but it might start.
But you can get get 120A to a car battery from an old Dodge hemi Alternator at 14.2V driven by an electric motor or an idling car.
Without knowing all your specs, I can’t be certain what will work cheaper or as well as your OEM batteries.

Using a car battery as a starter and a Power Supply for operation is a good solution. In a car, the alternator runs at 14.2V to burn off the lead sulphate but pulsers work better but will interfere with AM radios so it not suitable for a running car( You may remember old cars uses to emit radio noise from copper sparkplug wire, now its 50 kohm carbon wire). A battery de-Sulphator ( I have a lot of experience with)  is disabled below 12.8V typically and runs only when the charger is ON so it will not function with a 12V PSU (unless modified either by raising PSU voltage or lowering the Pulsator threshold).  When a car goes off with a light load the battery quickly goes to 12.8V and 12.5V means full charge  ~>95%, 11.5 means almost dead < 5% SoC. When a battery goes "dead" it is always caused by 1 cell, the weakest in a runaway condition. Never leave a car battery at <=0% SoC < 11.5V or they sulphate quickly. It can be restored to life if caught within a month or so over the quiet season , check Vbat.

The whole switching and control system is 12v. With ignition on you operating the hydraulic motor by the levers and a solenoid and relays click but that's it.. The motor is rated 120amp at 12 volts. The motor does start with a 95ah 12v car battery. Is it ok to connect this in parallel to the power supply or could it damage it?

OEM batteries cost around £1000! Looking for a cheaper alternative as I am always close to mains power

The charger is going to have a fit getting the battery to the same voltage then its ok, But then the battery needs a pulse desulphenator long term. So some mods are useful.

perfect if you leave power on & desulpator all the time and add choke at charger source to block pulses. then idle power is very low and battery always stays at 12V 50% SoC if car battery. I knew the inventor & tested the original pulse desulphator on motive power batteries and car batteries and it worked on a dead battery slow over a charger in a about a week restoring s.g to the bad cells., then maintained a longer life, but I don't think the CHinese clones are as good but then only $21

Would it be possible to use a supercapacitor instead of a battery? How long does an electric motor pull a large current when starting?

Do you known how to compute the startup energy and the energy in a cap between 2  voltages with a 5% drop?  It is not enough. Supercaps are only useful when you can convert all the energy without shutting down your PSU

A motor will need more current to start than it will to run, and a regulated supply will often not provide the needed starting current. They tend to shut down when loaded much past their limit.
A battery on the other hand is sort of a soft supply, they can act in a more dynamic way allowing the load to pull much more than their rating for a short time. In vehicle batteries you will see this listed as cold cranking amps, a battery rated at 75 A can have a CCA of hundreds of amps.
